# circle inscribed into isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

i am trying to solve following problem:
suppose that legs AB=BC=30  in isosceles triangle,and center of inscribed circle divides altitude into 12:5 part,our aim is to find base,my problem is that i dont know what is equal radius or  there is know any  angle,so could not understand how to  solve it,even i could not use  Pythagorean theorem,because it would take a long calculations,please help me guys,i am  trying to solve it right now,but no success yet

Comment: isosceles circle ?

Comment: sorry  i have edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be the centre of the incircle. Join $O$ to the three vertices.

It is not absolutely clear what ratio $12:5$ means. Let $M$ be the middle of the base. Maybe (i) $BO:OM=12:5$,  or maybe (ii) $BO:OM=5:12$. (It will turn out that (ii) can't happen.)

We examine the consequences of (i).  Let the base be $2y$ (I don't like fractions).
Let $BO=12t$ and let $OM=5t$.

We calculate the area of triangle $BAC$ in two different ways. The area is half of base times height, so it is $(1/2)(2y)(17t)$, that is, $17yt$.

The area is also the sum of the areas of $\triangle BOA$, $\triangle BOC$, and $\triangle OAC$. This sum is $(1/2)(30)(5t)+(1/2)(30)(5t)+(1/2)(2y)(5t)$, which is $150t +5yt$.
We conclude that
$$17yt=150t+5yt.$$
Thus $12y=150$, and therefore $2y=25$.

Next we examine possibility (ii).  The analysis is similar. We find pretty quickly that $y$ is "too big" (the Triangle Inequality is violated).

Comment: @dato:  If we let the altitude from B through O meet the base at D, I was reading the question to be $BO=\frac{12}5 OD$.  dato:  am I right?

Comment: yes yes  i understood now,thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

$\Delta OBD \sim \Delta AB'B$

[image]

Comment: Rather $\Delta ODB \sim \Delta AB'B$